# Compare lines of text and export results to excel

Tags: list, python-3.x, iteration

I'm trying to put into a variable each opened text.

```
    files_list = ["N1.txt", "N2.txt", "N3.txt", "N4.txt", "O1.txt", "O2.txt", "O3.txt", "O4.txt"]

j = 1
i = 0
num = len(files_list)
while i < num:
    for file in files_list:
        opentxt = open(files_list[i])
        tovariable = opentxt + str(j)
        i += 1
        j += 1
```

I know that "tovariable" line isn't correct..
I want that variable to get each text file opened and put it into a variable "varj".
New to python, I'm trying to automate something at work.

UPDATE

Made it work. Maybe this will help guys like me in the future.

```
import xlwings as xw

def create_txt(h, ch):
    for txt in range(h):
        open("../check_results/{}{}.txt".format(ch, txt), "w")

try:
    create_txt(4,ch = "N")
    create_txt(4,ch = "O")
except:
    input("ERROR - check_results folder was not found! \n\n Please create a folder with the name > check_results and try again\n\n\n")
exit()

new_text = ['N0.txt', 'N1.txt', 'N2.txt', 'N3.txt']
old_text = ['O0.txt', 'O1.txt', 'O2.txt', 'O3.txt']

def compare_txt(k, m):
    match = []
    new_text_match = []
    old_text_match = []
    new_i = []
    old_i = []
     for i in range(k):
            n = open("../check_results/{}".format(new_text[i]), 'r').read().splitlines()
            o = open("../check_results/{}".format(old_text[i]), 'r').read().splitlines()
            n = " ".join(n).split()
            o = " ".join(o).split()
            j = 0
for nword in n:
        for oword in o:
            if nword == nword.upper() and oword == oword.upper():
                j += 4
            elif nword[0] == nword.upper()[0] and oword[0] == nword.upper()[0]:
                j += 3
            elif nword.lower() == oword.lower():
                j += 1
   try:
        under_percent = ((len(n) + len(o)) / 2) / j
        result = 100 / under_percent
        if result > 100: result = 100
        match.append("{}%".format(round(result, 2)))
        new_text_match.append(" ".join(n))
        new_i.append("{}".format(new_text[i]))
        old_text_match.append(" ".join(o))
        old_i.append("{}".format(old_text[i]))
        print("Match found! Check: {} - {}".format(new_text[i], old_text[i]))
    except:
        print("No match found in {} - {}".format(new_text[i], old_text[i]))


    nrow = []
    orow = []
for nlist in new_text_match:
    nseparate = "".join(nlist)
    nrow.append(nseparate)
for olist in old_text_match:
        oseparate = "".join(olist)
        orow.append(oseparate)
try:
    sht = xw.Book(r"../check_results/results.xlsx").sheets[m]
    sht.clear_contents()
    sht.range('A1').value = "It's a match!"
    sht.range('A2').options(transpose=True).value = match
    sht.range('B1').value = "Nx.txt"
    sht.range('B2').options(transpose=True).value = new_i
    sht.range('C1').value = "Text line from Nx.txt"
    sht.range('C2').options(transpose=True).value = nrow
    sht.range('D1').value = "Ox.txt"
    sht.range('D2').options(transpose=True).value = old_i
    sht.range('E1').value = "Text line from Ox.txt"
    sht.range('E2').options(transpose=True).value = orow
except:
    input("ERROR - results.xlsx file not found! \n Please create or paste results.xlsx in check_results folder.")
    exit()

compare_txt(4, 0)


new_text = ['N0.txt', 'N0.txt', 'N3.txt']
old_text = ['O2.txt', 'O3.txt', 'O2.txt']

compare_txt(3, 1)

input("\n \n \n Analysis complete! \n Check results.xlsx file")
```

Comment: In short, *don't*. Use a dictionary or list instead.

Comment: he said _new to python_ maybe an example to add to your suggestion @MartijnPieters

Comment: @putonspectacles: that's what the duplication link is for.

Comment: cool, didnt see that until your most recent comment.